# In a batch file, how can I exclude folders in a search?

Tags: batch, batch-file, search

I'm trying to search only for files, and thus exclude folders, but currently it includes folders. How do I exclude them in my search?

```
for %%# in (a b c d) do if exist "%cd%\%%#*" (
Echo %%#
)
```

I expect the code to say "b" when only a folder starting with "a" is in the current directory as well as a file starting with "b". Instead it always says "a" when a folder starting with a in the directory, but no file starting with "a".

Comment: Don't know the answer off the top of my head but I think there is a way to do this explained in the help for FOR. Run `for /?` and read about the variable expansion rules.

Comment: Use `for /F %%# IN ('dir /B /A:-D')`. Or use `forfiles`.